# How to install Flex Builder 3 plugin to eclipse Mars.2

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, builder, eclipse-mars

We have been using Flex Builder 3 for years, and there are a lot of projects has flex mxml codes for front end. 
Now I am trying to upgrading Eclipse from Ganymede(3.4.2) to Mars(4.5.2). I am wondering is there a way to use Flex Builder plugin with Editor and debugging features? There should be a backwards compatibility for these plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with [Eclipse Profiles](http://profiles.yatta.de). If you're able to install the Plugin(https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/yatta-profiles)into your Ganymede Eclipse you can migrate your Eclipse to Mars with it.

The Eclipse versions are supported upon Kepler but give it a try...